# Adding a value into the variable in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Select column_1,column_2 from table1 ;

I need this column_1 and column_2 values into variables so that i can do some manipulation before inserting into another table.

Thank you for all the help

Comment: You cannot insert multiple rows into a variable. Can you expand your question to explain what you are trying to do together with the code you have so far.

Comment: @P.Salmon I am trying to get column values into variables so that i can do some manipulation before inserting into another table. 
`BEGIN declare @cat_name varchar(100); declare @id int; select @cat_name = category_name , @id = last_id from category where category_id= v_type; END` but it is giving me error.

Comment: Declared variables must not start with @ in a stored program (procedure in this case)

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @VAR1 INT
DECLARE @VAR2 INT

SELECT 
@VAR1 = column_1,
@VAR2 = column_2
from Table
```

You can do something like this to set the params and do what you'd like with them.

Comment: I did it like this
BEGIN

declare `@cat_name` varchar(100);
declare `@id` int;
select @cat_name = category_name  ,@id = last_id from category where category_id= v_type;
END

But while saving it is giving error 
MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@cat_name varchar(100); declare @id int; select @cat_name = category_name ,@i' at line 3

Comment: Declared variables must not start with @ in a stored program (procedure in this case)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really given much information to work on but maybe something like this will do

```
drop procedure if exists p;
delimiter $$

create procedure p ()
BEGIN 
declare cat_name varchar(100); 
declare cat_id int; 
select  id,username into cat_id,cat_name
 from users where id= 1; 
select cat_name,cat_id from dual;

END  $$
delimiter ;
```

Where users looks like this

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from users;
+----+----------+--------------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+--------+-------------+-----------+
| id | userName | photo        | status | ts                  | events_participated | fb_uid | Column_name | post_type |
+----+----------+--------------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+--------+-------------+-----------+
|  1 | John     | john.png     |      1 | 2016-12-08 13:14:24 |                   1 |      1 | 12346       | photo     |
|  2 | Jane     | jane.png     |      1 | 2016-12-08 13:14:24 |                NULL |      2 | 12346       | photo     |
|  3 | Ali      |              |      1 | 2016-12-08 13:14:24 |                NULL |      3 | 12346       | photo     |
|  6 | Bruce    | bruce.png    |      1 | 2016-12-08 13:14:24 |                NULL |      6 | 12346       | photo     |
|  7 | Martha   |              |      1 | 2016-12-08 13:14:24 |                NULL |      7 | 12346       | photo     |
|  8 | Sidney   |              |      1 | 2016-12-08 13:14:24 |                NULL |      8 | 12346       | photo     |
| 10 | Charlie  | charlie.png  |      1 | 2016-12-08 13:14:24 |                NULL |     10 | 12346       | content   |
| 12 | Elisa    |              |      1 | 2016-12-08 13:14:24 |                NULL |     12 | 12346       | content   |
| 14 | Samantha | samantha.png |      1 | 2016-12-08 13:14:24 |                NULL |     14 | 12346       | content   |
| 15 | Hannah   | hannah.png   |      1 | 2016-12-08 13:14:24 |                NULL |     15 | 12346       | content   |
| 16 | Hannah   |              |      1 | 2016-12-08 13:14:24 |                NULL |     16 | 12346       | content   |
| 17 | Kevin    | kevin1.png   |      1 | 2016-12-08 13:14:24 |                NULL |     17 | 12346       | content   |
| 18 | Kevin    | kevin2.png   |      1 | 2016-12-08 13:14:24 |                NULL |     18 | 12346       | content   |
| 19 | Ruth     |              |      1 | 2016-12-08 13:14:24 |                NULL |     19 | 12346       | content   |
| 20 | xyz      | NULL         |   NULL | 2017-08-18 12:54:40 |                NULL |   NULL | NULL        | content   |
+----+----------+--------------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+--------+-------------+-----------+
15 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

When called the result is

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> call p();
+----------+--------+
| cat_name | cat_id |
+----------+--------+
| John     |      1 |
+----------+--------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```